# C# Avalonia MVVM - Binding DataTable to DataGrid

Tags: c#, mysql, mvvm, avalonia

I have a DataTable that I get through MySqlConnection. I tried to bind `DataTable.DefaultView` to Avalonia’s DataGrid using DataContext but it displays wrong DataTable info. I also tried to use DataContext with Items but couldn’t figure it out.

[image: Wrong info in DataGrid]

I found a lot of solutions with WPF but not Avalonia. I expect DefaultView to show the table data like on this screenshot:

[image: Expected data]

Here is the code:

```
var dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM {SelectedTable}", CurrentConnection);
var dTable = new DataTable();
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);

GridContext = dTable.DefaultView;
```

Edited: I need DataGrid to dynamically adapt to different tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a poco class represent your table

```cs
public class tableObj
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? TestName { get; set; }
}
```

and a collection property of this class

```cs
ObservableCollection<tableObj> GridItems { get; } = new();
```

your DataGrid should Bind to this `GridItems`

```xml
<DataGrid Items="{Binding GridItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

now whenever you add or remove any item from `GridItems` it will reflect automatically to your UI

```cs
var dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM {SelectedTable}", CurrentConnection);
var dTable = new DataTable();
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);

foreach (DataRow row in dTable.Rows)
{
    var tr = new tableObj();
    tr.Id = int.Parse(row["id"].ToString()!);
    tr.TestName = row["TestName"].ToString();
    GridItems.Add(tr);
}
```

---

### update

with the same approach you can bind to multiple tables first define poco classes for your table

```cs
public class table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? TestName { get; set; }
}
public class table2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? TestName2 { get; set; }
}
```

define `GridItems` as a list of objects

```
private List<object> _gridItems ;
List<object> GridItems
{
    get => _gridItems;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _gridItems, value);
}
```

each time you bring data from diffrent table update the list

```cs
var dAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM {SelectedTable}", CurrentConnection);
var dTable = new DataTable();
dAdapter.Fill(dTable);

var tempList = new List<object>();
switch (SelectedTable)
{
    case "table1":
        foreach (DataRow row in dTable.Rows)
        {
            var tempObj = new table1();
            tempObj.Id = int.Parse(row["Id"].ToString()!);
            tempObj.TestName = row["TestName"].ToString();
            tempList.Add(tempObj);
        }
        break;
    case "table2":
        foreach (DataRow row in dTable.Rows)
        {
            var tempObj = new table2();
            tempObj.Id = int.Parse(row["Id"].ToString()!);
            tempObj.TestName2 = row["TestName2"].ToString();
            tempList.Add(tempObj);
        }
        break;
}
GridItems = tempList;
```

Comment: Thanks!
But I have another question:
What if there are a lot of tables with different fields? Is it possible to make TableObj dynamically change it’s fields?

(I need it to adapt to different tables)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use my. Filled DataTable in my example named reportsByHours, using Avalonia 11.0.0

```
    var dataTable = new DataGrid();  
    dataTable.ItemsSource = reportByHours.AsDataView();
    foreach (DataColumn column in reportByHours.Columns)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn 
            { Header = column.ColumnName,Binding = new Binding($"Row.ItemArray[{column.Ordinal}]") });

    }
    var grid = this.FindControl<Grid>("Grid1");
    grid.Children.Add(dataTable);
    dataTable.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
```